# Laravel conditional subquery with related model last entry

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent, relation

I try to build a query on related model which `hasMany` relation, where I want to query `users` with `properties` where last property has `unit_id, group_id or team_id`

what I tried but does not works

```
$users = User::with('properties', function($query) use($catId) {
                $query->where('team_id', $catId)
                    ->orWhere('group_id', $catId)
                    ->orWhere('unit_id', $catId);
            })->get();
```

this one returns all records

another try

```
$q = User::with(['properties' =>function($query) use($catId) {

                $query->latest()->where('team_id', $catId)
                    ->orWhere('group_id', $catId)
                    ->orWhere('unit_id', $catId);
            }]);
```

which returns again all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `with`, use `whereHas` :

```
$users = User::whereHas('properties', function($query) use ($catId) {
          $query->where('team_id', $catId)
                ->orWhere('group_id', $catId)
                ->orWhere('unit_id', $catId);
})->get();
```

Comment: @fefe Then an upvote / accept answer is in order... ;-)